# How do you really create a zero-length binary value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing an ODBC binding and I decided to implement support for `binary` and I've found that if I insert `0x`, supposedly the "empty string" [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql#binary-constants), it returns a buffer of one byte with zero in it. Clearly, that does not have length `0`:

```
1> CREATE TABLE demo (bar BINARY)
2> GO
1> INSERT INTO demo VALUES (0x)
2> GO
(1 rows affected)
1> SELECT * FROM demo WHERE bar = 0x00
2> GO
bar 
----
0x00

(1 rows affected)
1> SELECT DATALENGTH(bar) FROM demo WHERE bar = 0x00
2> go

-----------
          1
```

However, if you select it directly, it is empty:

```
1> SELECT DATALENGTH(0x)
2> go

-----------
          0

(1 rows affected)
```

So it seems like pulling something from the table has some kind of "minimum" of one zero byte?

The problem I have is that we don't have a very basic put/get law "what you put in is what you get out". If someone uses my ODBC binding and inserts empty data, they will not get empty data back. This is broken.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is simple `BINARY` is like `CHAR(1)`. You need to use `VARBINARY`.

From 
[binary and varbinary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql)

> binary [ ( n ) ] **Fixed-length binary** data with a length of n bytes, **where n is a value from 1 through 8,000**. The storage size is n bytes.

and

> varbinary [ ( n | max) ] **Variable-length binary data.** n can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes. The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes. **The data that is entered can be 0 bytes in length.** The ANSI SQL synonym for varbinary is binary varying.

```
CREATE TABLE demo (bar VARBINARY(size));
INSERT INTO demo VALUES (0x);
SELECT DATALENGTH(bar), * FROM demo;

--length    bar
-- 0        0x
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c54f5fbed09651c1a0ea4bc0336563a1)**